# CSS: prefix the li items with an image , possible?

Tags: css, image

Is it possible to prefix the "li" items with a small image ? I didn't find a suitable css attribute for it.

Comment: You want the image instead of a bullet or in addition to a bullet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an image for the bullet point:

```
ul { list-style-image: url("fancybullet.gif"); }
```

Failing that, you cold set the list-style-type to none, and then use CSS to place an image in the right place, like [in this article.](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listamatic/vertical05.htm)

Comment: By coincidence, just worked on a question in which list-style-image can be problematic (centering the image). My solution (not saying it was the best, though so far it seems to be!) was to set a background image instead of using list-style-image: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10068769/css-vertical-align-the-text-in-li-item-doesnt-work By all means use list-style-image (that's what it was meant for!!) but just an FYI in case you run into trouble. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the CSS :before pseudo-selector.

```
li:before { content: url(image.jpg); }
```

Note this may not work completely correct in IE8 and below.  [Here's some more information on the :before and :after selectors.](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/07/13/learning-to-use-the-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-in-css/)

I feel you may be better off doing this in Javascript however using a library like jQuery.  I assume this is a problem that needs a dynamic solution after HTML is rendered to the screen, in this case it may be best to use Javascript.