# CSS: vertical align the text in li item , doesn't work

Tags: css, image

I use a list-style-image for li items , and a single-line text.

[image]

But it looks bad, so I want to vertically align the text to the middle of the image.

I should use vertical-align: middle , right ? But it didn't work for me.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> This is an demo </title>
        <style>
            body {
                background-color: #464443;
                color: white;
            }
            ul {
                list-style-image: url('bg.png');
            }

            li {
                vertical-align: middle;
            }

        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <ul>
            <li>abc</li>
            <li>abc</li>
            <li>abc</li>
            <li>abc</li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A satisfactory way to do this (imo) is to not use list-style-image, instead using the background property to set the "bullet" (note I substituted my own placeholder image since I just copied/pasted from a fiddle). Your padding and other dimensions will vary depending on the size of the "bullet" image.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/huBpa/1/

```css
body {
  background-color: #464443;
  color: white;
}

 ul {
   list-style: none;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
 }

 li {
   background: url('http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-32-32-1.jpg') no-repeat;
   line-height: 32px;
   vertical-align: middle;
   padding-left: 40px;
 }​
```

Comment: agreed. `background` is a far-more reliable + accurate method

Comment: You could be right, Muhd, but only depending on definition: it "works" just fine with multiple lines, but the bullet is always at the top. This is very much the standard for bulleted lists, though. Unless I'm misunderstanding, in which case if you do a fork of my fiddle to show the problem, I'd be interested to see it!

Comment: @Muhd maybe using sprite offset technique would workaround it?

Answer (score 4):

This is what I would use. I don't use vertical align and instead use padding to move the text around to be wherever I want it to be.

```
    ul {
            list-style: none;
            margin-left: 0;
            padding-left: 0;
    }

    li {
            padding: 10px 10px 15px 20px;
            background-image: url(images/arrow.png);
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: 0px;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Add line-height to li. Make sure it is the same height as the image

`

> ```
> li {
>             vertical-align: middle;
>             line-height: 30px; 
>         }
> ```